# Cant autowire `WebTestClient` - no auto configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

We are using spring framework 5 and spring boot 2.0.0.M6 and we are also using `WebClient` for reactive programming. We created test methods for our reactive rest endpoints and so I looked up for some example on how to do it. I found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-webflux/src/test/java/sample/webflux/SampleWebFluxApplicationTests.java) one or [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/) and many others which where all the same. They just autowire a `WebTestClient`. So I tried the same:

```
@Log
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    public void getItems() throws Exception {
        log.info("Test: '/items/get'");

        Parameters params = new Parameters("#s23lkjslökjh12", "2015-09-20/2015-09-27");

        this.webClient.post().uri("/items/get")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(params), Parameters.class))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                .expectBody(Basket.class);
    }
}
```

I cannot run this because I get the error:

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'WebTestClient' type found.
```

So it does not seem that there is a auto configuration existing. Do I use the wrong version or what is the matter here?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Annotate your `MyControllerTest` test class with `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` annotation. That should solve the issue.

Comment: yes thank you. another possible annotation would be `@WebFluxTest(MyControllerTest.class)`

Comment: Doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: I see the error "could not autowire WebTestClient" if I remove webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT). Why is it needed ?

Answer (score 47):

The accepted answer keeps throwing that error for me, instead I had to add the webflux starter in addition to the test starter in Spring Boot 2.0.3:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then use the standard web test annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        this.webClient.get().uri("/ui/hello.xhtml")
          .exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
    }

}
```

Comment: still does not work for me when run with junit 5... same exception. but the deps are like here.

Comment: @ses, can you ask a question with your case?

Comment: Dependency + `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` + `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` worked.

Comment: The documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/AutoConfigureWebTestClient.html suggests that only web flux applications are supported. So web flux dependency should be required.