# spring boot: how to configure autowired WebTestClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

Are there any properties available in Spring Boot to configure the @Autowired WebTestClient? For instance, how to set the servlet context path (or just some base path for that matter) on WebTestClient?

Here's how my web tests are configured now:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTestClass{

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient cl;

  //the rest of it
}
```

In other words, what is Spring Boot equivalent of

```
WebTestClient client = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
    .baseUrl("http://localhost:<random port>/myServletContext").build();
```

I didn't find anything useful in documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

building webTestClient using current application context, no need to hardcode uri and port number

```
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        this.webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(this.context).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `server.servlet.context-path=/myServletContextPath`.

Comment: No, that sets the context path on the server side, but the client assumes it to be /. That's the whole point of posting the question. And I have tried it, of course.

Comment: Did you happen to check the following link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226651/cant-autowire-webtestclient-no-auto-configuration

Comment: yes, even commented on it long ago. I'm not sure how is it relevant to my question. I get the same result with `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` annotation as I get without it.

Comment: Even though it is set in the server side, the client can still pick it up by declaring it:         `@Value("${server.servlet.context-path:/defaultContext}")
    private String contextPath;`