# WebTestClient throws "No qualifying bean ... as autowire candidate"

Tags: spring-boot, webtestclient

I currently wrote a put request I wanted to test via WebTestClient. I followed some tutorials and adapted my case to it. Testing the request results in an error:

"NOSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}"

I looked up some solutions on SO like this one: [Cant autowire `WebTestClient` - no auto configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226651/cant-autowire-webtestclient-no-auto-configuration) but couldn't make it work, despite of the hints there.

Here is the test code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class DemonstratorApplicationTests {

private P4uServiceImpl p4uService = new P4uServiceImpl();

@Autowired
WebTestClient webTestClient;

@MockBean
ReqP4uAccount account;

@Test
void testPutAccount(){

    ReqP4uAccount request = p4uService.buildRequest("testAccount");

    this.webTestClient.put()
            .uri("/account")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(request, ReqP4uAccount.class)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody(P4uAccount.class);
}
}
```

Has anyone an idea what's wrong with the test setup? Thx in advance

Comment: Did you validate that your pom.xml has the same dependencies (TEST) dependencies as the SO link you pasted?

Comment: Dependencies I included are: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-test, spring-boot-starter-webflux @SMA

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following works:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;
```

If you remove `(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`, **it will fail.**

---

If you look at the WebTestClientAutoConfiguration , you can see that it has
`@ConditionalOnClass({ WebClient.class, WebTestClient.class })`  and that could be why it wont work, unless Springboot starts up the web application context during `(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

```
/**
 * Auto-configuration for {@link WebTestClient}.
 *
 * @author Stephane Nicoll
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass({ WebClient.class, WebTestClient.class })
@AutoConfigureAfter({ CodecsAutoConfiguration.class, WebFluxAutoConfiguration.class })
@Import(WebTestClientSecurityConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class WebTestClientAutoConfiguration {
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I have followed your example to the letter and I still get Unsatisfied dependency.  I gave up and went back to TestRestTemplate which works out of the box.